# How to convert this array in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array(
(int) 1 => 'igor.cesar@soreq.com.br',
(int) 5 => 'igorpol@gmail.com',
(int) 6 => 'kkk@asasa.com'
)
```

I want to convert to this:

```
array('igor.cesar@soreq.com.br','igorpol@gmail.com','kkk@asasa.com')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: arrays have to have keys, so what are you wanting them to be?

Comment: Don't you pretty much have that already. `array('igor.cesar@soreq.com.br','igorpol@gmail.com','kkk@asasa.com')` will give you the same thing except for adding new indexes.

Comment: `array('igor.cesar@soreq.com.br','igorpol@gmail.com','kkk@asasa.com')` is a way to initialize your array. I believe you need to read what are [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function:

```
array_values($yourarray);
```

Comment: don't work. I just want the emails

Comment: @IgorMartins Care to explain how it doesn't work? It does give just the emails. In fact, your initial array already had just the emails. Ignore the keys if you wish.

Comment: @IgorMartins are you sure that you have an array and not a string?

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this.

```
foreach($yourArray as $v)
{
 $newArray[]=$v;
}
```

explanation

for each value of your array put it in a new array called $newArray

Comment: There is a built-in function meant specifically for this use case.

Comment: @crush Why vote me down for this? both way work.

Comment: I'll remove down vote, but this method is wildly inefficient in comparison to using the built-in function. If he decides he needs to do some other complex logic, then it might be relevant.

Comment: @crush yes but it does not give any key in the array, look at the array he want. he dont want any key. array_values returns all the values from the input array and indexes the array numerically.

Comment: Every array has indexes/keys...